# Copy nodes in XSLT also copies namespace to each items Node

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my XML input which cant be changed and comes from RSS feed
In the output the namespace gets copied to each Item nodes which I don't want. How do I get rid of this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:hr="http://www.w3.org/2000/08/w3c-synd/#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cb="http://www.centralbanks.org/rss/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">

    <item rdf:about="/News-and-Publications/Media-Releases/2018/Chaly-Mah-joins-MAChairman.aspx">
        <title>Chaly Mah joins MAS Board of Directors; n</title>
        <link>http://www.mas.gov.sg/News-and-Publications/Media-Releases/2018/Chaly-Mah-joins-MAS-Board-of-Directors-DPM-Tharman-re-appointed-as-Chairman.aspx</link>
        <dc:date>2018-04-20 10:13 AM</dc:date>
        <description></description>
        <cb:news>
            <cb:simpleTitle>Chaly Mah joins MAS Board of Directors; </cb:simpleTitle>
            <cb:occurenceDate>2018-04-20 10:13 AM</cb:occurenceDate>
        </cb:news>
    </item>
    <item>
    </item>

</rdf:RDF>
```

And XSLT I have created is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"       
     exclude-result-prefixes="rdf">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF">
        <Records>
            <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        </Records>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:element name="Record">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the output the namespace gets copied to each Item nodes which I don't want. How do I get rid of this?

```
<item xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
      xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
      rdf:about="/News-and-Publications/Media-Releases/2018/Chaly-Mah-joins-MAS-Board-of-Directors-DPM-Tharman-re-appointed-as-Chairman.aspx">
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records>
    <item xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
          xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
          rdf:about="/News-and-Publications/Media-Releases/2018/Chaly-Mah-joins-MAS-Board-of-Directors-DPM-Tharman-re-appointed-as-Chairman.aspx">
        <title>Chaly Mah joins MAS Board of Directors;</title>
        <link>http://www.mas.gov.sg/News-and-Publications/as-Chairman.aspx</link>
        <dc:date xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">2018-04-20 10:13 AM</dc:date>
        <description/>
        <cb:news xmlns:cb="http://www.centralbanks.org/rss/">
            <cb:simpleTitle>Chaly Mah joins MAS Board of Directors; DPM </cb:simpleTitle>
            <cb:occurenceDate>2018-04-20 10:13 AM</cb:occurenceDate>
        </cb:news>
    </item>
```

Comment: Please explain in detail which result you want exactly. Given that your input documents has elements in various namespaces and you use `xsl:copy` (which creates a shallow copy of the context node, preserving the qualified name including the namespace) there will be namespaces from the input copied to the output. The `copy-namespaces="no"` only omits in-scope namespaces not relevant for the name/namespace of the node.

Answer (score 1):

`xsl:copy` copies the nodes with their namespaces.

You need to rename all nodes and namespaces to their local-name without the namespace. This would look like this (replacement for your all nodes and attributes matcher)

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, your matcher for `item` is never called, because your XML has the default namespace `xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"`. That means every element in the XML that has no namespace prefix is part of this namespace.

So you need to declare this namespace in your **XSL** too

```
xmlns:rss="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
```

And then change your matcher to

```
<xsl:template match="rss:item">
```

By the way: if you want to get rid of the namespace declarations that are no more used, you have to declare the namespaces in your XSL and then add them to the result exclusions

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" 
    xmlns:hr="http://www.w3.org/2000/08/w3c-synd/#" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
    xmlns:cb="http://www.centralbanks.org/rss/" 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rss="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="rdf rdfs hr dc cb rss">
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you so much. Only issue I see is its coming as <item> .... </item> from input xml. How can the <item> node be renamed to <Record>? so it come like this <Record> .... <Record>

Comment: Your item matcher is never called, I have extended my answer

Comment: Worked. Thanks.